# Angular - window.search and router.queryParams do not match when using HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to access query params from Angular Route.
I use the standard code prescribed to do this all over internet and it works fine.

```
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {...}


  this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params=> {
     console.log('Target', params.get('target') );
  });
```

When the URL is `http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard?target=my-test-server`, the value is printed correctly as "my-test-server" in browser console log.

For same URL, if I try to print the value of `window.location.search` in Browser's console, I get empty value.  I expected it to print the value of query params which is `?target=my-test-server`.

When the URL is `http://localhost:4200/?target=my-test-server#/dashboard`, then, the Angular query params is empty.  And if I print `window.location.search`, I get the value `?target=my-test-server`.

**Problem:**

I have another application redirecting user to my app, and they are using URL format of  `http://localhost:4200/?target=my-test-server#/dashboard` and my application is looking for 'target' in router's queryParamMap.

Is this even possible or I need to change my Angular code to parse the `window.location.search` to get the value of `target`.

In summary, 
What is the URL that will work for both browser and Angular?

Answer (score 0):

In this url :-

```
http://localhost:4200/?target=my-test-server#/dashboard
```

query params are at wrong place and browser will not give you query params after hash.

Comment: I understand that - my question is are "window.location.search" and queryParamMap mutually exclusive?  What will be the right URL that will work for both Angular and Browser?

Comment: don't have hash and have query params in last, but for page refresh you will be required to configure server to serve index.html in case of not found. Hash are generally used for anchor scrolling in pages.